# Should I assume weak pointer usage if there is any cyclic relationship?

Tags: c++, c++11

Say I've a `Person` class, with `name`, `age`, and `bestFriend` as properties. I'm confused about how to best represent `bestFriend`. Multiple `Person` instances can be pointing to the same `bestFriend`, which rules out `unique_ptr`. And there is also a possibility of a cyclic relationship, which rules out `shared_ptr`. So, is using `weak_ptr` ideal in this case? Would I even want to use smart pointers here instead of just raw pointers?

```
class Person {
    std::string name;
    int age;
    std::weak_ptr<Person> bestFriend;
};
```

Comment: Who own `Person`, which are lifetime of `Person` ?

Comment: You could shove the value objects in a container and use raw pointers to express the structure (beware of invalidating pointers during network building/changes).

Comment: Can a `Person` be their own best friend? Why not just a reference? Can a best friend die and its object destroyed, while a `Person` lives on?

Comment: @Tas I think it makes sense for the best friend to die and the `Person` to move on.

Comment: imo Using `std::weak_ptr` won't keep your nodes alive *unless* you also have a container load of `std::shared_ptr`s keeping them alive. In that case your `std::weak_ptr`s are just acting like very slow *raw pointers*. You may as well store whole `Person` objects in a container and use *raw pointers* to express the network relationships.

Comment: @Galik: but `weak_ptr` would avoid to have to reset manually `bestFriend` when a `Person` is destroyed.

Comment: @Jarod42 It depends. I think it would be faster to simply have a "I am dead" flag in the `Person` objects. Then you avoid the locking overhead of accessing a `std::weak_ptr` every time. If, on the other hand, you wanted to parallelize this, then you would have to add your own locking so using `std::weak_ptr` may be more attractive in that situation. But I like the idea of being able to access your objects sequentially *very very* quickly if you store them in a contiguous container rather than at the end of `std::shared_ptr`s.

Comment: Does a Person, as an instance object, have identity?  That identity can be its address, such that a pointer of some sort would be suitable.  But that does not serialize well, if serialization is a concern.  Another choice would be an additional field that is a unique value (such as a UUID or a sequence number which persists as part of serialization).  Then the best friend could be that UUID or sequence number, or some other token if there is no best friend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pointers (both raw and smart) express certain *ownership*. Thus, to pick a proper pointer, you need to decide on the ownership. If something *owns* an object, then if this something dies, the object has to die too. Does my best friend has to die if I die? I don't think so. Thus, I don't *own* my best friend. This rules out `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr`, since those are *owning* smart pointers.

So we have two choices: `weak_ptr` or a raw pointer. This depends on how you are going to keep track of alive persons.

The simplest approach might be to rely on smart pointers to keep track of alive persons. This means, you have some storage of `shared_ptr` to all persons, and then you store `weak_ptr` to point to them from another persons. In this case I know that if I have a friend and `weak_ptr::lock()` returns `nullptr`, this means my friend is dead. Convenient, but not very flexible. E.g. imagine you need to issue a letter to a family when a person dies. When would you do this? In person's destructor? This would be mix of responsibilities. In a custom deleter of a `shared_ptr<Person>`? That would break encapsulation, since this custom deleter might have many functions.

Another approach is to keep track of alive persons by a dedicated manager. Again, you need some storage where all persons live. You can store them by value, or via `shared_ptr` - up to you. Then you store raw pointers to those objects. (Note: if you store them in a vector, which size is an object to change, storing raw pointer to them is not a good idea, because of possible reallocation). In this case you cannot tell by looking on a raw pointer, whether my best friend is still alive or not. We would need to check the manager to get this information. This is more flexible, but I'd say less safe, since we have dangling pointers built-in in our system.

I'd recommend not to store raw pointers for that's sake, but to go for an ID. Store person's ID instead, and have a registry of persons by ID. This registry will handle all the mess and will properly detect situation, when somebody wants to access a dead person, trigger a post-man to issue a letter to relatives, etc. This also allows to distinguish situations when I don't have a best friend and when my best friend is dead. `weak_ptr` would return `nullptr` in both of these situations.

PS If we were storing `shared_ptr` to best friends, that would mean a person would be alive only as long as they are someone's best friend... So true, but not in software development world, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

The smart pointers `std::unique_ptr<>` and `std::shared_ptr<>` are used for [unique or shared **ownership**](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2011/06/27/unique-ownership-shared-ownership/) of the object pointed to. In the case of your `Person`, this concept of ownership hardly makes sense and the best friend is presumably best represented by a simple raw (observing) pointer:

```
struct Person
{
    std::string name;
    date_type born, died=date_type::never;
    const Person *bestFriend = nullptr;     // defaults to none

    time_type age() const
    { died==date_type::never? date_type::today()-born : 0; }
};
```

Having said that, you must ensure that these pointers remain valid at all times. To this end, the `Person`s could be stored using a `std::deque<Person>` which allows to add new `Person`s w/o invalidating any existing `Person` pointers. However, you cannot remove an arbitrary `Person` w/o invaliding pointers to other `Person`s, so better mark a `Person` as dead than to remove it (you may have another list of all living `Person` pointers). This has the advantage to avoid dangling best-friend pointers (but you will get best friends who are dead).

**Warning.** As you have failed to provide more detail of the intended purpose of `class Person`, the above suggestions are based on some speculation and may not actually be useful, depending on your actual intent.